# How to catch Exception in vba code running in python

Tags: python, vba, win32com

I have a VBA macro that runs in Python,

if the macro fails, how can i catch it in python? currently it hangs and will wait for a user response. How can i bypass this? i cant use `On Error GoTo 0` as i will have no idea is the vba completed successfully or not.

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open("/myexceldirectory/excel.xlsm")

try:
    xl.Application.Run("excel.xlsm!mymacro.mymacro")
except Exception as e:
    print("i failed {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Change the `Sub` to a `Function`, put the error handling in the VBA function, then have it return a success/fail value?

Comment: is ti possible for the python part to capture the success/fail value in vba? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the optimal way of doing it, but it works.

The idea is:

1. Create a temporary class that wrap the macro that you are intending to call.
2. Create a function that create an instance of the temporary class
3. Call the newly created function

Python can then capture any error that this class throws.

**NOTE:** The macro can still get stuck if the macro has MsgBox popup

```
from win32com import client as win32client

import clr
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
from Microsoft.Vbe.Interop import vbext_ComponentType

def run_macro(xl, wb, sheetname, macro_name):
    # Dynamically add VBA class to workbook
    f = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule)

    # Avoid duplicate names
    tempGuid = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]

    f.Properties.Item("Instancing").Value = 2
    f.Name = "CLS_" + tempGuid
    f.CodeModule.AddFromString(
        "Public Sub TempClassCall()\r\n" +
        "   Call " + macro_name +
        "\r\n" +
        "End Sub\r\n")

    # Dynamically add VBA module to create dynamic VBA class
    f2 = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
    f2.Name = "MOD_" + tempGuid
    f2.CodeModule.AddFromString(
        "Public Function instantiateTempClass_{0}() As Object\r\n    Set instantiateTempClass_{0} = New CLS_{0}\r\nEnd Function".format(tempGuid))

    try:
        wb.Activate()
        tempObject = xl.Run(sheetname + "!instantiateTempClass_{}".format(tempGuid))
        tempObject.TempClassCall()
    except com_error as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        self._wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(f)
        self._wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(f2)
```